# How to make pynput.keyboard.listener thread keep running in the background even when main app is terminated

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, pynput

I have a main GUI app made out of *Tkinter*, which includes a button called *"start"* , which when pressed initiates the `pynput.keyboard.listener` thread  .

Its listens to the keystrokes all right .

But when I terminate the app (by clicking *'x'*) , the keystrokes listener thread also terminates .

I want the thread to be persistent and keep listening , even when the GUI is closed .

Here is the code  .

counter.py

```
import pynput.keyboard
import threading
from threading import Event
import ctypes

class KeypressCounter(threading.Thread):
    
    def __init__(self):

        # import pynput.keyboard
        # import threading
        # from threading import Event
        # import ctypes

        super().__init__()
        self.key_count = 0 
        self.stop_event = Event()

    def run(self):
        listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_press,daemon=False)
        listener.start()
    def on_press(self, key):
        self.key_count += 1
        if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.esc:
            print("esc pressed") 
            self.on_endsession()
        print("counter:",self.key_count)    
    def on_endsession(self):
        with open("key_count.txt", "w") as f:
            print("writing to file")
            f.write(str(self.key_count))

        self.stop_event.set()

def main():
    keypress_counter = KeypressCounter()
    keypress_counter.start()

    while True:
        if keypress_counter.stop_event.is_set():
            break                    
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The tkinter frame , app.py

```
from tkinter import *
from counter import KeypressCounter 

def start() :
      KeyCounter  = KeypressCounter()
      KeyCounter.start()


window_size = '1200x600'

    # Create the root window
window = Tk()


window.geometry(window_size)

keyBoardFrame  = Frame(window,width=100,height=100,bg='green')

button  = Button(keyBoardFrame,text='start',bg='red',fg='white',command = start)
button.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')

window.mainloop()
```

The counter is written to *key_count.txt* before it terminates(don't know how ) .

And after window is closed, nothing gets written to the *key_count.txt* .

but I want the thread to keep listening to all the keystrokes in the background .

Comment: Why do you terminate the app if you want it to keep running? What are you really trying to accomplish with this program? Also, what is this "x" that you click on? You said, "when the GUI is closed," but there's nothing that looks like GUI library calls in your example. Are you closing a terminal/console window from which the "app" was started via a command prompt?

Comment: @SolomonSlow , this is the listener thread code , the GUI code seems irrelevant , its just a button when pressed will call this thread creation function . and the "x" is the standard close icon at the top right of the window . I want the GUI to be used just to start the background keystrokes listener , afterwards the GUI window is not necessary and can be closed .  The main idea is to see the no. of keystrokes when the window is reopened probably sometime in the future .

Comment: OK, So your application creates a GUI window (code not shown), and you want to know why closing the window kills the process? Maybe you could ammend your question to say what GUI framework/library you are using, and show the code that creates the window.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Edited ,.

Comment: Call `listener.join()` after `listener.start()`.

Comment: @acw1668, Good point, but once OP does that, then there will be no point in having the `KeypressCounter` class inherit from `Thread`. The main thread already is doing nothing except waiting for the `KeypressCounter` thread to end. And, if the `KeypressCounter` thread does nothing except wait for the `Listener` thread to end, that sounds to me like there's at least one more thread than the program really needs.

Comment: Without that `KeypressCounter` thread, the application will be terminated once the window is closed.

Comment: @acw1668, And, what about the main thread? Why can't the main thread be the one that creates, and starts, and waits for the `Listener` thread? Why does the main thread have to do nothing except wait for the `KeypressCounter` when the `KeypressCounter` is doing nothing except waiting for the `Listener`? Or, alternatively, why can't the main thread _end_ while the `KeypressCounter` thread does nothing except wait for the `Listener`? Why must _two_ threads do nothing but wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the *listener* is a *daemon* thread, it will be terminated when the main thread terminates.

You can change the *listener* to a non-daemon thread so that the main thread will wait for it after closing the main window. Also `KeypressCounter` does not need to inherit from `threading.Thread` in this case:

```py
class KeypressCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key_count = 0

    def start(self):
        # change listener to self.listener so that it can be accessed in other class methods
        self.listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_press)
        self.listener.daemon = False  # set it to a non-daemon thread
        self.listener.start()

    def on_press(self, key):
        self.key_count += 1
        if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.esc:
            print("esc pressed")
            self.on_endsession()
        print("counter:",self.key_count)

    def on_endsession(self):
        with open("key_count.txt", "w") as f:
            print("writing to file")
            f.write(str(self.key_count))

        # terminate the listener
        self.listener.stop()
```